# simple math/casting bug in Java that I just keep on missing?

Tags: java, loops, math, floating-point

So i've spent a good three hours trying to solve the problem below. My logic seems right, my syntax seems right, but for some reason the code just won't listen to me. How typical.

```
        float counter = 0;
        float pColor = counter / ((float)Math.abs((x_end - x_start)));

        System.out.println("FIRST EVER PCOUNTER:" + pColor);
        System.out.println("FIRST EVER X START IS: " + x_start);
        System.out.println("FIRST EVER X END IS: " + x_end);
        System.out.println(x_end + "  " + x_start);

        // part of another program
        while(x != x_end){

            x+= step_x;
            counter++;                  
            System.out.println("Count is:" + counter);

            if(p<0){
                p+= twoDy;
            }
            else{
                y += step_y;
                p += twoDyMinusDx;
            }

            System.out.println("pColor is: "+pColor);
            System.out.println("p1.c.r: "+ p1.c.r);
            System.out.println("x_end is: " + x_end);
            System.out.println("x_start is:" + x_start);
            System.out.println("");
```

So all the print statements above is to check whether **pColor** is changing or not. For some reason,all the print statements says that pColor is 0.0

```
FIRST EVER PCOUNTER:0.0
FIRST EVER X START IS: 341
FIRST EVER X END IS: 350
350  341
Count is:1.0
pColor is: 0.0
p1.c.r: 1.0
x_end is: 350
x_start is:341

Count is:2.0
pColor is: 0.0
p1.c.r: 1.0
x_end is: 350
x_start is:341

Count is:3.0
pColor is: 0.0
p1.c.r: 1.0
x_end is: 350
x_start is:341

Count is:4.0
pColor is: 0.0
p1.c.r: 1.0
x_end is: 350
x_start is:341

Count is:5.0
pColor is: 0.0
p1.c.r: 1.0
x_end is: 350
x_start is:341

Count is:6.0
pColor is: 0.0
p1.c.r: 1.0
x_end is: 350
x_start is:341

Count is:7.0
pColor is: 0.0
p1.c.r: 1.0
x_end is: 350
x_start is:341

Count is:8.0
pColor is: 0.0
p1.c.r: 1.0
x_end is: 350
x_start is:341

Count is:9.0
pColor is: 0.0
p1.c.r: 1.0
x_end is: 350
x_start is:341
```

As you can see, counter is constantly increasing, but every single pColor remains at 0.0. What is wrong with it?

Comment: float pColor = counter / ((float)Math.abs((x_end - x_start))); your counter is zero and zero / llll is what?

Comment: "My logic seems right, my syntax seems right, but for some reason the code just won't listen to me." - this is your problem.  You'll make progress faster if you stop assuming that everything you do is "right" and the computer is somehow being mean to you.  Assume you're wrong - first, last, and always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
    float counter = 0;
    float pColor = counter / ((float)Math.abs((x_end - x_start)));
```

The result of `pColor` is always **0.0** because **0** divided to any number is **zero**.

for example:

```
System.out.println( 0 / 1);
```

output:

```
0
```

Another Example:

> 0 divided by any number is 0. This result is explained by the fact
>   that no number, even 0, can go into 0. In the example below 9 cannot
>   go into 0 at all, resulting in the 0 answer.
>
> Example: 0 / 9 = 0

[Source of the Example](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_0_divided_by_a_number)